# auto-width the input in mat-header-cell

Tags: angular, mat-table

I want to put an `<input>` in my mat-header-cell to serve as filtering, and I want the input width to adjust based on the .mat-column-{ width:50px}.

template

```
<table mat-table ...>
 <ng-container ...>
  <th mat-header-cell...>
    <div fxLayout="column">
     <span>{{someColumnTitle}}</span>
     <input>
    </div>
  </th>
 </ng-container>
</table>
```

css

```
.mat-column-<allColumnsHasThis>{
 width: <differentValuesEachColumn>
}
```

My problem is all input width are equal in all of the columns
[image]

I set the width to 100% for input and div, but it has no effect. It is not following the width that I set on .mat-column- classes

Answer (score 0):

I get it using a work-around (I have serius dudes it's a optimal solution, but I can not imagine any another way)

I use ViewChildren to get all the cells and create an array of observables

```
  @ViewChildren('cell') cells:QueryList<ElementRef>
  $columnWidth:Observable<any>[]=[]
```

I want that each td in the grid was a cell, so, in cells we has all the "td"s. The order goes from up to bottom and from left to rigth, so I can create a function

```
  getWidthObservable(index:number)
  {
      const element=this.cells.find((x,i)=>i==index)
      const width=element?element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width:0
      return of(width>=50?width-50+'px':'0px').pipe(startWith('0px'))

  }
```

That return the width of one cell less 50px. Just only need in ngAfterViewInit make some like

```
ngAfterViewInit()
{
    //I enclosed in a setTimeout to avoid the error "change after checked"
    setTimeout(()=>{
       displayedColumns.forEach((x,index)=>{
            this.$columnWidth[index]=this.getWidthObservable(index*this.dataSource.length)
       })
    })
}
```

Now see the "magic" in the .html, each column we use

```
  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <!--use $columnWidth[0] for the first column
              $columnWidth[1] for the secod column
              ...
      -->
      <ng-container *ngIf="$columnWidth[1]|async as width">
      <input [style.width]="width">
      </ng-container>
      </th>
      <!--see the "#cell" to get the ViewChildren-->
    <td #cell mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

And use as .css

```
th{
  width:1%;
  padding:0!important;padding-left:25px!important;
}
```

In the [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rejyh7?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts) I colored each th in a different color and add a `@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])` so if you resize the navigator the input width change